# Without using angle measure, how do I prove that vertical angles are congruent?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, congruences, angle, congruences-geometry

Assume that X is a point between A and C, that X is also between B and D, and that these points are not all collinear. Then the angles AXB and CXD are called vertical angles.
Prove that vertical angles are congruent.

I'm not sure how to do this without using angle measure, but since I am in Euclidean Geometry we can only use the Axioms we have so far and previous problems. We only have SSS and SAS and from these axioms we have proven how to construct right angles, perpendicular angles, midpoints, and angle bisectors.

I'm really confused on where to start with this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the axioms?

Comment: We have have Axiom 1 which says: Each segment AB can be assigned a positive number L(AB), called the length of AB, so that following properties hold. (i) The length of the unit segment is 1. (ii) Two segments are congruent if and only if they have the same length. (iii) If A, B, and C are three points with B between A and C, then L(AC) = L(AB) + L(BC).

Comment: Axiom 2 is Side-Side-Side congruency
Axiom 3 is Side-Angle-Side congruency
We can also used previously proven problems, but I'm not sure if they can help.

Comment: How can you tell when two angles are equal, so you can use SAS?

Comment: With an angle bisector, or using congruent triangles (CPCTC)

Answer (score 1):

That's Euclid book 1 prop 15.

You have
$\angle AXC + \angle CXB
=\angle CXB + \angle BXD
$
since both sum to 
a straight angle.

Therefore
$\angle AXC =\angle BXD
$.

Comment: This proof uses angle measure, which is not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I am not allowed to use addition of angles yet.
We also have Axiom 1 which says:
Each segment AB can be assigned a positive number L(AB), called the length of AB, so that following properties hold.
(i) The length of the unit segment is 1.
(ii) Two segments are congruent if and only if they have the same length.
(iii) If A, B, and C are three points with B between A and C, then L(AC) = L(AB) + L(BC).

Comment: It seems that you would have to construct triangles with angles AXC and BXD and show they are congruent (probably by SSS). Then the corresponding angles are equal.